# Sap Webi Count Function

Tags: count, multivalue, webi

I have a problem in count function.

I have an online table which is auto generated from Database.

I want to create a summary according to data in that table.

I need a count of a value which are same in some columns. As example given below.

[image: Example table]

This is auto generated table online. Ticket number has unique value.

I want to get a count of "Restored within Time" by "Severity" and Region.

I am using below formula.

```
=count([TicketNumber] Where ([RestoredWithInTime] ="Yes" And [Severity]="High" And [Region]="Central"))
```

In above formula it should give me a count like 2. But it is showing 0.

If I use only one condition then it works, like

```
count([TicketNumber] Where ([RestoredWithInTime] ="Yes")
```

or

```
=count([TicketNumber] Where ([Severity]="High"
```

gives me accurate output. But if there is more than one condition then it shows only 0 count.

Formulas which I have used for this are...

```
=count([TicketNumber] Where ([RestoredWithInTime] ="Yes" And [Severity]="High" And [Region]="Central");Distinct)

=count([TicketNumber]) Where ([RestoredWithInTime] ="Yes" And [Severity]="High" And [Region]="Central") (It Shows #MULTIVALUE Error)

=sum(count([TicketNumber]) Where ([RestoredWithInTime] ="Yes" And [Severity]="High" And [Region]="Central"))
```

Is there anything related to measures or dimensions?

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, Where should be outside Count function. can you check this.

```
=count([TicketNumber]) Where ([RestoredWithInTime] ="Yes" And [Severity]="High" And [Region]="Central")
```